# Juniper MX204 base license

Tags: juniper

We want to purchase a juniper mx204 without license and I checked https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/license/licensing/topics/topic-map/software_licensing_requirements.html "Table 6: License Variants for MPCs"
Juniper mx204 without license just support 6milion routes in RIB and 2 million routes in FIB and it supports all layer 2, 2.5, 3 features such as bgp, acl, rate limiting, shaping,... ?
Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: You should actually be reviewing the Flex licensing guide - https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/license/licensing/topics/concept/flex-licenses-for-mx-and-service-cards.html

Comment: so i can not have ebgp and gre without license on mx204?

Comment: Ultimately, the licenses are only to allow JTAC support of the licensed feature(s). The CLI/system will not prevent anything from working (with minor exceptions like subscriber management or MACSEC).

Comment: So this means that we can use all features such as ebgp,jflow,acl,shaping,l3-interface and all other features without additional licenses? but if we need jtac support then we should purchase licenses for each of them or use flex license? do I understand correctly?

Comment: I'll put all of the necessary detail in an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to be reviewing the newer [Flex](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/license/licensing/topics/concept/flex-licenses-for-mx-and-service-cards.html) licensing model if you're trying to figure out what you want to buy, that said, it's always best to talk to your account team.

In most cases the license just entitles you to JTAC support for the software features that particular license supports. Most software features are not hard enforced by the license. Meaning that not having a license will not prevent you from configuring those features, nor will it prevent them from working. However, JTAC will not be able to support those features if you engage them.

Some software features like subscriber management, MACSEC, and others are hard enforced and will not work until you add a valid license.